# MySQL query giving division by zero error

Tags: php, mysql

I have this sql query

```
$sql =  'SELECT id, texto FROM `db_name`.`table_name` WHERE ( CONVERT( `texto` USING utf8 ) LIKE '%q%' ) ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0,15';
```

I am getting following error

```
Warning division by zero at line 40 

Query was empty
```

Although when I copy the same query to my phpmyadmin terminal for sql and do query there it gives result

**Update**

```
function get()
        {
            $sql =  'SELECT id, texto FROM `db_name`.`table_name` WHERE ( CONVERT( `texto` USING utf8 ) LIKE '%fincas%' ) ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0,15';


            $rc= $this->parent->parent->database->query($sql);

            $post='';
            while($row= $this->parent->parent->database->readRows($rc))
            {
                echo $post;
                echo str_replace('"','&quot;',$row['texto']).'"'.$row['id'];
                $post="\n";
            }

        }
```

Comment: it seems that you got above error from php script. Add full php script

Comment: post the related php code as well, looks like it's some php error instead of SQL.

Comment: mark the line no 40 and you need to correct quotation in the query

Comment: Is `fincas` a constant?

Comment: @machineaddict no it was just a string I was passing to search I will have to replace with a variable containing the search key from input text box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**first error** is your php error check the php code where you perform some math division on line 40

**second error** comes due to use your single quotes in sql query `'%q%'`.correct it by enquote you sql string in double quotes

```
$sql =  "SELECT id, texto FROM `db_name`.`table_name` WHERE ( CONVERT( `texto` USING utf8 ) LIKE '%q%' ) ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0,15";
```

Comment: I suspect it's the same row, the outside-the-quote `%q` (modulo) with an undefined q probably gives a division by zero.

Comment: its not modulo it is like syntax.

Comment: no my sysntax is right because it works fine in the Mysql Console

Comment: @SKRocks It's `LIKE` syntax if it were quoted correctly, but since `%q%` is outside the quote, you end up with a string modulo an undefined variable `q`.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson oh! so how I can fix this ?? :( sorry I am very new to mysql

Comment: @SKRocks i updated the complete function bro please have a look . thats all I have got in my plugin class

Comment: @Vikram Use double quotes around the sql query just like the answer says. You can't have single quotes inside single quotes.